# How to get documents in firestore, whose document IDs are stored in the list?, i.e bring only those documents....?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a list that contains the document Ids of a particular collection "users", and I want to get documents only present in this list, and these documents are in "users" collection as mention before.

Code:

```
  getUsers() async
     {
       double radius = 0.3;
      String field = "GeoPosition";
       print(currentUser.point.longitude);
       GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(latitude: currentUser.point.latitude,  longitude: currentUser.point.longitude);
        var collectionRef = Firestore.instance.collection('user_locations').document(currentUser.pincode)  .collection('Users_complete_address_and_geopoint');
        this.stream =  geo.collection(collectionRef: collectionRef).within(center: center, radius: radius, field: field, strictMode: false);   
        Future<List<certainrangeusers>> users1 =  stream.first.then(
        (documents) => documents.map((doc) => certainrangeusers(
         id: doc['userPhone'],
         )
        ).toList());  
         users1.then((val) async{
        QuerySnapshot snapshot = await  Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('id', isEqualTo: val.first.id).getDocuments();
         List<User> users = snapshot.documents.map((doc) =>  User.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
        setState(() {
         this.users = users;
          });
       });
   }
```

Firebase Structure:
[Click here for the firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JGeR.jpg)

Code In image format:

[Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MggVE.jpg)

1. In orange box, "users1" is a list having document IDs...of users 10km users
2. In the pink box, we r using the value of the list...
3. In the green box, we need to pass the document ids present in the above list...

P.s: I am using "val.first.id" just to bring the document present at first in the list........But I need to bring every document present in that list...so that's a point I have struck...

Comment: can you get the document for the first id?

Comment: @Adnankarim I was able to get the document for the first Id, i have just uploaded the firebase structure

Comment: check my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here how to search for all documents from the list id

instead of:

```
await  Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('id', isEqualTo: 
 val.first.id).getDocuments();
```

use this:

```
await  Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('id', whereIn: 
 val).getDocuments();
```

Since you have a list of `certainchangeuser`, do this to get the ids.

```
users1.then((val){
  // Get the ids
  List ids = [];
  for (var value in val){
    ids.add(value.id);
  }
  //Then
  QuerySnapshot = await 
    Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('id', 
    whereIn:ids).getDocuments();
....
});
```

Comment: Error: "Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'certainrangeusers' ", got this error

Comment: make sure "val" is a list

Comment: Well this only takes "id's" not list of "certainrangeusers"

Comment: class certainrangeusers {
  final String id;
  certainrangeusers({this.id});
}

Comment: is the class for the list<certainrangeusers> = [];

Comment: Yes your are passing an object that contains id, but it only accepts ids like "List ids = ["23","41","23"]

Comment: Future<List<certainrangeusers>> users1 =  stream.first.then(
        (documents) => documents.map((doc) => certainrangeusers(
         id: doc['userPhone'],
         )
        )

Comment: i am doing as above

Comment: but it only accepts ids like "List ids = ["23","41","23"]  , how to do this....considering my scenario

Comment: @saivaraprasadboggula check the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213065/discussion-between-sai-vara-prasad-boggula-and-adnan-karim).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61600322/13462594 , is the continuation of the question

Answer (score -2):

You can use a transaction for this purpose. [Firestore transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions)

Comment: Transactions are for reading then writing documents, not just reading.

Comment: As i am new to flutter