# How to sort particular items in model that represent firebase documents of particular collection? (P.S: click below for the well answered question)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[Click here for the previous version well solved question by me and others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61584880/13462594)

I want to **sort** the items in the model which represents the firebase documents of particular collections.Also this model contains the document Ids of the users(**which will be sorted according to the distance**) of the **collection "users" and i will bring those documents only from "users"** collection. **I have calculated the distances from the current-user to the other users** and i want bring the nearest users for this user. **I have tried following code:**

**ScreenShot:** [*In the pink box area, whole calculation is done and assigned and documents brought from firebase*]
[[image: In the pink box area, whole calculation is done and assigned and documents brought from firebase]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynvp1.jpg)

**Got Error:**

Got this error: "Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Invalid Query. 'in' filters cannot contain 'null' in the value array., null)" –

**Detailed Code:**

**Temp model:**

```
     class certainrangeusers {
     final String id;
     final double away;
     final GeoPoint userpoint;
      certainrangeusers({this.id, this.away, this.userpoint});
      }
```

**Variables:**

```
   List<certainrangeusers> info= [];
```

**code:**

```
    getUsers() async
      {
       double radius = 0.3;
       String field = "GeoPosition";
       print(currentUser.point.longitude);
             GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(latitude: currentUser.point.latitude,
         longitude: currentUser.point.longitude);

       var collectionRef = Firestore.instance.collection('user_locations').document(currentUser.pincode)
         .collection('Users_comp  lete_address_and_geopoint');

          this.stream =  geo.collection(collectionRef: collectionRef)
              .within(center: center, radius: radius, field: field, strictMode: false);

            Future<List<certainrangeusers>> users1 =  stream.first.then((documents) => documents.map((doc) => 
          certainrangeusers(
         id: doc['userPhone'],
        userpoint : doc['GeoPosition']['geopoint'],
       )
        ).toList());

          users1.then((val) async{
           for(var value in val){
            info.add(certainrangeusers(
            //away: await Geolocator().distanceBetween(currentUser.point.latitude,currentUser.point.longitude, value.userpoint.latitude, value.userpoint.longitude),
              away: center.distance(lat: value.userpoint.latitude,lng: value.userpoint.longitude),
                         ));
                  info.sort((a,b) => a.away.compareTo(b.away));
                }
              List ids = [];
              for(var value in info){
             ids.add(value.id);
                 }
            QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('id', whereIn: ids).getDocuments();
           List<User> users = snapshot.documents.map((doc) => User.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
            setState(() {
            this.users = users;
                 });
              });
          }
```

Comment: Got this error: "Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Invalid Query. 'in' filters cannot contain 'null' in the value array., null)"

Comment: If you have information to add to your question, you can edit it directly instead of adding a comment.

Comment: Done Doug Stevenson...

Comment: @DougStevenson can u help me out here?

Comment: Hey, @DougStevenson , I have solved the issue of null by adding the "id: value.id" in the for loop of adding away , but required thing here is when i store the sorted document ids in the "List ids" using for loop again, i want to bring documents from firestore in that order itself, not in order the documents that are stored in the firestore.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you that you can't have a null value in the array that you use for this query:

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .where('id', whereIn: ids)
    .getDocuments();
```

You're going to have to figure out why `ids` contains a null value and fix that.  We can't see where that's coming from based on what you're showing here.

Comment: Hey , I have solved the issue of null by adding the "id: value.id" in the for loop of adding away , but required thing here is when i store the sorted document ids in the "List ids" using for loop again, i want to bring documents from firestore in that order itself, not in order the documents that are stored in the firestore.

Comment: P.S: It took me , soo long to respond bcoz, i was quarantined in the hospital.